# ngFor over Array of Observables

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to present an `Observable<Array<Observable<Steward>>>` using `*ngFor` in an Angular 7 template. Do you understand what is the problem with "Solution 1" below?

**Solution 1:**
I tried the following solution and it worked, but I had the problem that the items were refreshed with a very high frequency, for example making it impossible for the user to select the output:

```html
<div *ngIf="term.stewards$ | async as stewards">
    <span *ngIf="stewards?.length > 0">
      <dt><b class="text-muted" placement="top"
        ngbTooltip="Persons responsible for the book. Any changes will be reviewed/approved by these persons.">STEWARDS</b></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li *ngFor="let steward$ of stewards">
            <span *ngIf="steward$ | async as steward">
              {{steward.getName()}} ({{steward.principalId}})
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** Then I changed the solution to use a typescript method transforming `Array<Observable<Steward>>` to `Array<Steward>`, and I got it working without the flickering.

```html
<div *ngIf="term.stewards$ | async as stewards">
    <span *ngIf="stewards?.length > 0">
      <dt><b class="text-muted" placement="top"
        ngbTooltip="Persons responsible for the book. Any changes will be reviewed/approved by these persons.">STEWARDS</b></dt>
      <dd>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li *ngFor="let steward of getObjectArray(stewards)">
            <ng-container *ngIf="steward; else loaderIcon">
                {{steward.getName()}} ({{steward.principalId}})
            </ng-container>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
  </span>
</div>
```

Below is the typescript function `getObjectArray(stewards)`:

```js
getObjectArray(obsArray: Array<Observable<any>>): Array<any> {
  return obsArray.map(obs => {
    let object = null;
    obs.subscribe(msg => object = msg);
    return object;
  });
}
```